# How to find location of a user in youtube from his comment

Tags: python, youtube, geolocation, sentiment-analysis

I'm making an application about sentiment analysis.
So I want to find the location of a user that post the comment in a Youtube video ?
Is there any approach to do that ?

**EDIT**

For example I want to know the location; I mean the emplacement ( City or Country or even geo-localisation) any thing that can refer to his emplacement.

I'm using python right now, so I can fetch information of a given video, and his comments, but i don't know any approach to find the location of the comment owner.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you [edit] your question adding what have you tried so far?. If I understand you correctly, you want get the location of a user who post a comment. Please clarify: which video are you using for this?, what do you mean with "location" exaclty? (longitude, latitude, location of the comment in the comment thread)?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited the question.
I want to know location which is country or city

Comment: if you still looking for a solution for this, you can also use YouTube Analytics API.

Comment: Yes I am still looking for a solution.
Youtube don't give that information, it give only the localisation of the video owner not the comment owner.

Comment: My best guess is that you have to read carefully the YouTube Analytics documentation - that's due I read about the impact of videos in different countries. See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query). Also, YouTube Analytics is for videos and channels owned by the user *(i.e. you can't use YouTube Analytics for other channels where you're not the owner)*.